# Binding xml to an ASP.NET treeview. How do I get the specific nodes?

Tags: asp.net, xml, treeview

I see that the data is there when I autogenerate. I can't seem to understand how to get the values from the nodes? Any reference anywhere on the ways to set the properties of databandings/TreeNodeBinding?

Like I need the name inside here

```
  <TaxonomyName>Resource Enhancement</TaxonomyName>
```

Using

```
   <asp:TreeView ID="tvSubmissionCategories" runat="server" DataSourceID="xdsSubmissionCategories"
                AutoGenerateDataBindings="False">
                <DataBindings>                  
                    <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Taxonomy" Text="TextThing" />
                </DataBindings>
            </asp:TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the TreeNodeDataBound event it can be accessed with e.Node.PropertyName.